# How to sum values in xml?

Tags: xml, android-layout

Suppose I have 2 dimension values defined in an XML file and want to define a 3rd value that is the sum of the other 2 values. Is there a way to do that in the XML file?

Here is an illustration of what I would like to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <dimen name="top_element_size">10dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="element_spacing">5dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="bottom_element_top">@dimen/top_element_size + @dimen/element_spacing</dimen>
</resources>
```

And I would like to define `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bottom_element_top"` for the bottom element in a `frame` layout.
But it appears that `@dimen/top_element_size + @dimen/element_spacing` is not legal.

Comment: NO, you can't. You can only set the finite values.

Comment: you can't add values in XML file. If you want to set margin dynamically so you can set from Java code also. Hope this trick helps you.

Comment: @BobMalooga I'm not too knowledgeable about the meta of the site, but why should "That's not possible" be a comment and not an answer? If there truly is no way to do this, then it does answer my question, even though it's not a solution (because there is no solution).

Comment: Sorry to say it, but this question lacks the basics of Android programming...

Comment: @BobMalooga Sorry if you felt attacked by my comment above, that was not my intent, and no need to attack me back. I genuinely want to know why you think your comments above cannot be answers. And please don't take this the wrong way either, but what do you mean by my question lacking the basics of Android programming? Do you mean that I'm asking about something basic? That's true but it still doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: @Pooks: No, I didn't feel attacked. Nor I felt like attacking back - sorry if this passed. A one line "answer" is better suited as a comment, not as a real answer, which indeed explains something in detail. You will learn by frequenting SO. Yes, your question shows  lacks in the basics of the Android system. Android Developers is the best resource to learn the fundamentals (along with tuttorial sites). And this is said without any offensive meaning. You can find an exhaustive answer to your question here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: I don't put it as an answer, because it would be a "link only answer", which is deprecated on SO.

Comment: @BobMalooga Thanks for the explanations. Indeed, I did check the Android developer website and searched for an answer before asking the question. In fact, the code I posted is based on the basics of resource definitions and tries to expand on it. And it is true that nowhere does the Android documentation mention that you can add values of resources within the XML definitions. But you will agree that the Android developer website is far from exhaustive and is lacking in many areas, which is why I asked to see if there was some way not documented there.

Comment: I wish it was possible. Even though I think it makes no difference to precalculate the sum. Or, in some sense it makes difference since you don't ask the CPU do do another calculation. So - in a certain measure - it's faster, even if it's an unperceivable gain.

Comment: Haha nice answers ... you can with programatically,  firstly need get value (automatically get @dimens screen ) after you can sum with infinit values :) have fun

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot perform arithmetic or logical operations in xml file. Dynamically you can retrieve the data from the xml and sum the values in java code, then set that value as parameters to your LinearLayout or FrameLayout or any other widget.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is partly possible with [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

1. Enable data binding
2. Write [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for each tag where you want to use arithmetic.
   Since `@dimen/smth` returns float, adapter should take float:

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginTop")
   fun setTopMargin(view: View, topMargin: Float) {
       (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = topMargin.toInt()
   }
   ```
3. Use it in layout (! not in resources)

   ```
   <View
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@{@dimen/top_element_size + @dimen/element_spacing}"/>
   ```